# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

```
  Iterable<Parking> _parkingListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return Parking(
        car: doc.data['car'] ?? '', //problem
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? '', //problem
        num: doc.data['phone'] ?? '', //problem
      );

    }).toList();
  }
```

so the problem that I currently have is at the return Parking where it says that The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'. also I already did the doc.data['car'] ?? '', as well still having the same problem

Comment: try with `doc.get('name') ?? ''`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Iterable<Parking>` to `List<Parking>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` property of a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) is a function, so you need to use `()` to invoke it:

```
car: doc.data()['car'] ?? ''
```

Alternatively you can use the [`get` function](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/get.html) to get the field values.

I also recommend reading the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/) for FlutterFire, as there have been significant changes.